# If AWS is already backing up Dynamo, what's the point of doing my own backups?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a completely serverless application, with only lambdas and DynamoDB.

The lambdas are running in two regions, and the originals are stored in Cloud9.

DynamoDB is configured with all tables global (bidirectional multi-master replication across the two regions), and the schema definitions are stored in Cloud9.

The only data loss we need to worry about is DynamoDB, which even if it crashed in both regions is presumably diligently backed up by AWS.

Given all of that, what is the point of classic backups? If both regions were completely obliterated, we'd likely be out of business anyway, and anything short of that would be recoverable from AWS.

Comment: People make mistakes. Backups help mitigate this type of disaster.

Comment: In this case, it would be AWS making a gigantic mistake.

Comment: Maybe, AWS has made mistakes. More likely would be the case were a developer made a coding error or a disgruntled employee decided to delete the tables. I have seen the latter many times. Backups are just good policy for all forms of data. Also remember that point in time backups are useful to see the data state at a date in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Not all AWS regions support backup and restore functionality. You'll need to roll your own solution for backups in unsupported regions.

If all the regions your application runs in supports the backup functionality, you probably don't need to do it yourself. That is the point of going serverless. You let the platform handle simple DevOps tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Having redundancy with regional or optionally cross-regional replication for DynamoDB provides mainly the durability, availability and fault tolerance for your data storage. However along with these inbuilt capabilities, still there can be the need for having backups.

- For instance, if there is a data corruption due to an external threat (Like an attack) or based on an application malfunction, still you might want to restore the data back. This is one place where having backups is useful to restore the data back to a recent point of time.
- There can also be compliance related requirement, which will require taking backups of your database system.
- Another use case is when there is a need to create new DynamoDB tables for your build pipeline and quality assurance, it is more practical to re-use an already made snapshot of data from a backup rather taking a copy from the live database (Since it can consume the IOPS provisioned, affecting the application behaviors).